# How to add match conditions dynamically in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my code now I wanted to add year and name fields conditionally. how to achieve that?

```js
getRevenue = async sel => {
  var years = sel.selectedYear.split(",").map(Number);
  var data = await mongoose
    .model("revenues")
    .aggregate([
      { $match: { AccountName: sel.selectedAccount } },
      { $unwind: "$data" },
      { $match: { "data.Year": { $in: [...years] } } },
      { $match: { "data.Name": { $in: [sel.selectedProduct.split(",")] } } },
      { $group: { _id: "$_id", data: { $push: "$data" } } },
    ]);
  var info = {};
  info.revenue = getSum(data[0].data, "Value");
  info.volume = getSum(data[0].data, "Volume");
  return data;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the bug that you're returning `data`, not `info`, since `.aggregate()` takes an array, you can dynamically form the array. (`.filter(Boolean)` is the idiom for removing falsy items, `null`s in this case.

```js
getRevenue = async sel => {
  const years = sel.selectedYear.split(",").map(Number).filter(Boolean);
  const products = sel.selectedProduct.split(",").filter(Boolean);
  const aggregate = [
    { $match: { AccountName: sel.selectedAccount } },
    { $unwind: "$data" },
    years.length ? { $match: { "data.Year": { $in: years } } } : null,
    products.length ? { $match: { "data.Name": { $in: products } } } : null,
    { $group: { _id: "$_id", data: { $push: "$data" } } },
  ].filter(Boolean);
  var data = await mongoose.model("revenues").aggregate(aggregate);
  return {
    revenue: getSum(data[0].data, "Value"),
    volume: getSum(data[0].data, "Volume"),
  };
};
```